# PHP Create Timeslots with break timing using DatePeriod

Tags: php, datetime, php-5.3

I want to create time slots with start,end time & also break timing.

```
public function getServiceScheduleSlots($duration,$break, $stTime,$enTime)
{
    $start = new DateTime($stTime);
    $end = new DateTime($enTime);
    $interval = new DateInterval("PT" . $duration. "M");
    $period = new DatePeriod($start, $duration, $end);

    foreach ($period as $dt) {
        $periods[] = $dt->format('H:iA');
    }
    return $periods;
}
```

For ex.,
My service start time **10:00 AM** , End Time **12:00 PM**.
**Condition:**  each service time **30 min** & **15 min** break.

Above method returns like,

- 10:00 AM - 10:30 AM
- 10:30 AM - 11:00 AM
- 11:00 AM - 11:30 AM
- 11:30 AM - 12:00 PM

Expected results as,

- 10:00 AM - 10:30 AM
- 10:45 AM - 11:15 AM
- 11:30 AM - 12:00 PM

I want to add break time when each period starts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

How about this....

```
function getServiceScheduleSlots($duration,$break, $stTime,$enTime)
{
        $start = new DateTime($stTime);
        $end = new DateTime($enTime);
        $interval = new DateInterval("PT" . $duration. "M");
        $breakInterval = new DateInterval("PT" . $break. "M");

        for ($intStart = $start; 
             $intStart < $end; 
             $intStart->add($interval)->add($breakInterval)) {

               $endPeriod = clone $intStart;
               $endPeriod->add($interval);
               if ($endPeriod > $end) {
                 $endPeriod=$end;
               }
               $periods[] = $intStart->format('H:iA') . 
                            ' - ' . 
                            $endPeriod->format('H:iA');
        }

        return $periods;
  }
```

Comment: Superb work buddy , Now can you tell me that what should we do incase we want to add a 1 hour break between the start and end time ? that time should not be displayed in array